# How do I fix my damage calculation being so high?

Tags: c#, math, console-application

I have written some C# code for a Commandline RPG. Problem is: Whenever I hit the enemy, it receives a damage that is way too high.

I have made an int variable for the damage and also call DamageCalc() only once. Problem still occurs. 
I have the assumption that it could be the way i subtracted the Damage from the enemy's HP in line 154.

Here is the code to reproduce the problem. Excuse me for the length of it, but I don't know exactly where the problem occurs, so I cant make it even shorter than i already did.

[image]

Here you can see the boar with 5 HP. I hit the boar and do 4 Damage. Sadly, the boar gets 10 Damage and its HP goes down to -5.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Player
    {
        Archer archer = new Archer();
        Knight knight = new Knight();
        Assasin assasin = new Assasin();
        CurrentWeapon currentWeapon = new CurrentWeapon();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Klasse { get; set; }
        public int HP { get; set; } = 20;
        public int Level { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    class CurrentWeapon
    {
        public string WeaponName { get; set; }
        public float DamageMultiplier { get; set; } = 1;
    }

    class Enemy
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Attack { get; set; }
        public int HP { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }
        public bool Dead { get; set; } = false;

        //Konstruktor
        public Enemy(string _type, int _attack, int _hp, int _experience)
        {
            Type = _type;
            Attack = _attack;
            HP = _hp;
            Experience = _experience;
        }
    }

    class Archer
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; } = "Archer";
        public int BaseDamage { get; set; } = 6;
        public string WeaponType { get; set; } = "Bow";
    }
    class Knight
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; } = "Knight";
        public int BaseDamage { get; set; } = 5;
        public string WeaponType { get; set; } = "Greatsword";
    }
    class Assasin
    {
        public string ClassName { get; set; } = "Assasin";
        public int BaseDamage { get; set; } = 4;
        public string WeaponType { get; set; } = "Dagger";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static int GenerateNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Archer archer = new Archer();
            Knight knight = new Knight();
            Assasin assasin = new Assasin();
            CurrentWeapon currentWeapon = new CurrentWeapon();
            Player player = new Player();

            int DamageCalc()
            {
                if (player.Klasse == "Archer")
                {
                    float outputDamage = archer.BaseDamage * currentWeapon.DamageMultiplier;
                    return (int)Math.Round(outputDamage);
                }
                if (player.Klasse == "Knight")
                {
                    float outputDamage = knight.BaseDamage * currentWeapon.DamageMultiplier;
                    return (int)Math.Round(outputDamage);
                }
                if (player.Klasse == "Assasin")
                {
                    float outputDamage = assasin.BaseDamage * currentWeapon.DamageMultiplier;
                    return (int)Math.Round(outputDamage);
                }
                else { return 0; }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" What shall you be called?");
            player.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(player.Name);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Good, " + player.Name + " choose your class.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(archer.ClassName + " | DMG: " + archer.BaseDamage + " | Weapon Type: " + archer.WeaponType);
            Console.WriteLine(knight.ClassName + " | DMG: " + knight.BaseDamage + " | Weapon Type: " + knight.WeaponType);
            Console.WriteLine(assasin.ClassName + " | DMG: " + assasin.BaseDamage + " | WeaponType : " + assasin.WeaponType);

            string UserClass = Console.ReadLine();
            if (UserClass == "Archer")
            {
                player.Klasse = "Archer";
                Console.WriteLine("You are now an Archer.");
                currentWeapon.WeaponName = "Oak bow";
                Console.WriteLine("You got a " + currentWeapon.WeaponName + ".");
            }

            if (UserClass == "Knight")
            {
                player.Klasse = "Knight";
                Console.WriteLine("You are now a Knight.");
                currentWeapon.WeaponName = "Wooden sword";
                Console.WriteLine("You got a " + currentWeapon.WeaponName + ".");
            }

            if (UserClass == "Assasin")
            {
                player.Klasse = "Assasin";
                Console.WriteLine("You are now an Assasin.");
                currentWeapon.WeaponName = "Wooden Dagger";
                Console.WriteLine("You got a " + currentWeapon.WeaponName + ".");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            bool Play = true;
            while (Play)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to walk.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();

                int randomNumber = Program.GenerateNumber(0, 101);

                if (randomNumber <= 101 && randomNumber >= 0)
                {
                    Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy("Wild Boar", Program.GenerateNumber(5, 10), Program.GenerateNumber(2, 4), Program.GenerateNumber(6, 9));
                    Console.WriteLine(" A " + enemy1.Type + " appears! | ATTK: " + enemy1.HP + " | HP: " + enemy1.Attack);
                    while (!enemy1.Dead)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Use your " + currentWeapon.WeaponName + " and attack by pressing 'Q'.");

                        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                        {
                        int hitDamage = DamageCalc();
                        enemy1.HP -= hitDamage;
                        Console.WriteLine("You hit the " + enemy1.Type + "! | HP: " + enemy1.HP + " (You did -" + hitDamage +")");
                        if (enemy1.HP <= 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You killed the " + enemy1.Type + "! | +" + enemy1.Experience + " Experience!");
                            enemy1.Dead = true;
                        }
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to write some tests for your calculator.

Comment: Why don't you just lower the damage values?! or divide by 100 or any number of other solutions. It's really up to you

Comment: You lower the HP multiple times - once before you output anything and then again when you show how much you damaged them.  Change the `Console.WriteLine()` to just include `enemy1.HP` **not** `enemy1.HP - DamageCalc()`

Comment: "_I haven't tried anything yet because to me the code makes 100% sense_" But you already know that your code somehow, somewhere doesn't make 100% sense. Is suggest you use the debugger to learn what your code really does, and how its state (and the values of each involved variables) changes with every step during program execution. If you don't know abou the debugger yet, here are some handy guides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger

Comment: @Liam How do I do that? Isn't subtracting a way of lowering a value?

Comment: you subtract the damage from hp initially, then subract it upon printing

Comment: Each time you call DamageCalc(), damage is computed again. You have to store the result in a variable then use this variable in the output.

Comment: You call `DamageCalc` three times: first to decrease the enemies HP, second to print enemies HP, and third to output the damage. Each time DamageCalc will return a different value. Therefore DamageCalc should only be called once and stored in a variable. The second call is useless because you have already updated the enemies HP.

Comment: Damage is only subtracted once, the issue is that your HP and ATTACK outputs receive the other's value.. so HP is actually 3, reduced to -1, and printed as -5 (3 - (2 * 4))

Comment: Inspect this line of code VERY carefully: `Console.WriteLine(" A " + enemy1.Type + " appears! | ATTK: " + enemy1.HP + " | HP: " + enemy1.Attack);`

Comment: elgonzo's links are for VisualStudio.

Comment: @Varvalian. i edited my comment in the mean time because as i first posted the comment i screwed up pasting the links. The links should be visible now in my comment. And yes, Visual Studio has a powerful built-in debgugger (the guides i linked to are about the VS debugger). And while it is a powerful debugger, VS' debugger is also rather easy to use ;-)

Comment: Really funny namespace for a game :))))))))

Comment: @KevinGarnick, yeah, the game is known in French as Conso, and the chosen namespace reflects that: "_Conso, le App 2_"...

Comment: @elgonzo Didn't know ty for info

Comment: "I haven't tried anything yet because to me the code makes 100% sense" - this is your biggest problem.  Learn how to write good unit tests.

Comment: I have now made an int variable for the damage and also call DamageCalc() only once. Problem still occurs. [view changes](https://pastebin.com/5Huea1wH)

Comment: @Varvalian are you sure your HP is right, cuz whenever I start the game with knight the enemy has 2 HP ?

Comment: @Kevin Garnick I don't know wether i understand your question but when i start with knight the enemy hp is normal... https://prnt.sc/oclus1

Comment: @Varvalian yea but while debugging you can see that Wild Boar has only 2 HP.

Comment: @Varvalian here take a look https://prnt.sc/oclwmf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error:

```
Console.WriteLine(" A " + enemy1.Type + " appears! | ATTK: " + enemy1.HP + " | HP: " + enemy1.Attack);
```

You are printing HP on Attack and vice versa.

Second error:

```
enemy1.HP -= DamageCalc();
Console.WriteLine("You hit the " + enemy1.Type + "! | HP: " + (enemy1.HP - DamageCalc()) + " (You did -" + DamageCalc() + ")");
```

enemy1.HP has been already reduced (`-=`) by the damage, so when you print it do not subtract again (HP: " + (`enemy1.HP - DamageCalc())`)

Comment: Thanks. Had already fixed the second error but didnt notice first. Works now

Comment: @Varvalian You can use string interploation for output e.g.: 

``Console.WriteLine($" A {enemy1.Type} appears! ATTACK: {enemy1.Attack} HP {enemy1.HP}"); ``

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation for the ouput, since it's much easier to read.

`Console.WriteLine($" A {enemy1.Type} appears! ATTACK: {enemy1.Attack} HP {enemy1.HP}");`

```
var damage = enemy1.HP -= DamageCalc();
Console.WriteLine($"You hit the {enemy1.Type} HP: {damage}  You did {DamageCalc()} damage") ;
```

And you might consider to increase randomNumber , because your HP Number is between 2 and 3, that's why you can one shot them =D